# Magento and Symfony user session

Tags: symfony, session, authentication, magento2

Im new to both symfony and magento. One part of our website will be built using Symfony and the other Magento. I would like to know if it is possible to share user session variables between two of them. If so guide me with the flow and example code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

there is a [project on github](https://github.com/liip/LiipMagentoBundle) to accomplish this task.
It's still under development.

Another solution, but it depends on your needs, could be to play with the Symfony2 [event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html) (basically the BEFORE part) and playing with the Magento authentication, requiring the app/Mage.php file:

```
$session = \Mage::getSingleton("customer/session", array('name' => 'frontend'));
$session->start();
// [....]
// Check if the user is already loggedin
if ($session->isLoggedIn()) { 
  // Logged in 
}
// [....]
// Perform a login
if ($session->login($email, $password)) {
  // Logged in, here's your customer:
  $customer = $session->getCustomer();
  $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
}
```

and so on.